# When I'm called forth, times must be tough

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> I've got a puzzle for you to solve,
>
> Like always, in three parts.
>
> So start those engines, let those gears revolve
>
> And let's let the puzzling start
>
> ---
>
> My prefix is a common action
>
> You might do it every day.
>
> It's key to our communication,
>
> Though if you can't, there's another way.
>
> As seconds go by, the clock goes "tick!"
>
> And the hands get farther apart
>
> And the secret of my infix will finally click
>
> When you find clock's action's second part.
>
> My suffix is a friendly guy
>
> He always says "hello"
>
> While he drops out of Low Lunar Orbit
>
> In which he'll frequently go.
>
> As for my whole, that's a quite tragic tale.
>
> One which we'll all someday know
>
> When those who are there for you finally fail
>
> Into my clutches you'll go.

---

What am I?

Comment: I would guess that the last part can be found in this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_periodic_comets   or in this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numbered_comets   list

Comment: The minimum orbital period, according to those tables (except for 1) is 3+ years, which I wouldn't call "frequently". Although it might be a figure of speech. It's a plausible guess

Comment: or maybe this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit)

Comment: Can you give a hint? I've got some ideas, but they don't add up to anything meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just saw this puzzle bumped to the top.  I'll give it a guess:

My prefix is a common action
You might do it every day.
It's key to our communication,
Though if you can't, there's another way.

> Prefix: **hear**
>  Hear is a common action that we do every day to communicate.  Some people can't hear but they can use sign language.

As seconds go by, the clock goes "tick!"
And the hands get farther apart
And the secret of my infix will finally click
When you find clock's action's second part.

> Infix: **tock**
>  "Tock" is the clock action after "tick".

My suffix is a friendly guy
He always says "hello"
While he drops out of Low Lunar Orbit
In which he'll frequently go.

> Suffix: **he**
>  The word "he" is repeated many times.  Also "hello" minus LLO (drops out of Low Lunar Orbit) is "he".

As for my whole, that's a quite tragic tale.
One which we'll all someday know
When those who are there for you finally fail
Into my clutches you'll go.

> Answer: **heartache**
>  Heartache is something tragic tales are all about, and which we'll all someday know.  When people we count on let us down, we fall into heartache.
>
>  (We need to convert the infix **tock** to **tac** here, but the two sound similar).

Comment: Nicely done, sir JS1, you've solved this cryptic verse. The longer game, though, is not won. The path from here... gets worse

Answer (score 6):

My guess is:

> Photochemotherapy

Prefix:

> Photo -> "key to our communication"

Infix:

> toc -> Second part in "tick tock", albeit without "k"

Suffix:

> hemotherapy -> No idea about LLO, but there's "mother", which always says "hello"?

Additionally:

> According to the title, "When I'm called forth, times must be tough". There're 4 stages of cancer, fourth being the worst. Photochemotherapy being a possible treatment for cancer. And, of course, all in all, "As for my whole, that's a quite tragic tale." is quite so.

Comment: Whoops! Would you look at the time. Has it been 5 months already? No, this is not quite correct. First off, photos aren't quite what I was thinking by the "key to our communication". There's something more... ubiquitous.